Верно ли здесь поставлено тире?
Попробуйте рассказывать ребёнку о возможных последствиях его действий — так дети лучше воспринимают информацию.
Верно ли здесь поставлено тире? И, если позволите, подскажите, по какому правилу, спасибо.

В этом предложении возможны тире и единый знак (запятая и тире). Можно оставить тире, но я бы выбрала единый знак:
Попробуйте рассказывать ребёнку о возможных последствиях его действий, — так дети лучше воспринимают информацию.
Пояснение

Тему регулируют правила Розенталя § 45 и § 46, а также ПАС § 130.

В ПАС говорится, что единый знак в настоящее время утрачивает свою активность, но это утверждение сомнительно: этот вариант одинаково востребован как в классической, так и в современной литературе. Другое дело, что разницу между знаками не так легко определить и обозначить в правилах. Однако у Розенталя есть такая информация:
 8. Тире ставится перед местоименными словами так, такой, 
 таков, начинающими собой присоединительное предложение, 
 входящее в состав бессоюзного сложного предложения: Приказ 
 есть приказ — так его воспитал фронт (Вор.); Кривые улицы, 
 маленькие деревянные дома — такой была значительная часть 
 Москвы в начале XX века. Идти вперёд или погибнуть — таков 
 был выбор у партизанского отряда;

 В этих предложениях выражены суждения, субъект которых 
 назван в первой части, а предикат образует вторую часть. 
 Если логические отношения между обеими частями носят другой 
 характер, то между ними ставятся запятая и тире: 
 Загрязнение окружающей среды угрожает жизни на Земле, — так 
 дальше продолжаться не может (Газ.). [См. § 46, п. 2.]


Но как это правило применить на практике?  Знаки различаются на слух: пауза при постановке единого знака увеличенная, подчеркнутая, а для тире пауза просто обозначена. Семантика также разная: при постановке тире вторая часть предложения в БСП непосредственно включена в текст как необходимый элемент, а при постановке единого знака это скорее сопутствующий комментарий в присоединительной конструкции.

В заданном предложении речь, вероятно, идет о воспитании детей, поэтому там это попутный комментарий. А вот в статье "Правила хорошей памяти" можно поставить присоединительное тире, например:  Желательно переключаться с одного вида деятельности на другой — так информация лучше запоминается.


Но в этом предложении и пояснительное двоеточие можно поставить, так как эти знаки часто взаимозаменяемы.
В целом выбор тире или единого знака — это дискуссионный вопрос.

Благодарю за столь детальный и интересный ответ.

Спасибо вам за вопрос, он был  интересным и для меня.
